# regular expression in pexpect expect

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

I would like to put a regular expresion in a pexpect code that matches when the expect contains an ip address. The following is not working, it gives timeout.

```
index = process.expect(['192.168.0.1',pexpect.EOF,pexpect.TIMEOUT])
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this or what is the regular expresion I should write?

Answer (score 2):

Your first argument to `expect` only permits one IP address.  You should be passing a regular expression [per the documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn-expect).

A regular expression that will match IP addresses is roughly this:

`\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b`

(Source for more discussion on this [is here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html))

Note that you don't have to compile the regular expression with [python's re library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), expect will do that for you.

Comment: +1, but note that you don't have to compile the string, `exepect` will do it for you. "The pattern can be a StringType ... Strings will be compiled to re types". http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn

Comment: Not strictly correct to say that the original permits only a single, specific IP address -- it permits any string that has numbers in the right places, since unescaped `.`s are wildcards. The original would match `192!168@011` too, f'rinstance.

Comment: BTW, I tend to suggest using `[.]` in favor of `\.` to escape `.`s -- less risk of the wrong kind of string interpolation taking them out. (I don't see you suggesting raw strings here).

Comment: Exactly which regex to use is a complicated issue.  OP should read the link I provided for "more discussion" that makes some of these points.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the dots "." are escaped in the regex I provided, so 192!168@011 would not match.

Comment: Yes -- you made an assertion that *the original* regex in the OP's question would only match a single IP address. It's that assertion, not anything about the code you provided, that I was questioning.